# Сортировка списка строковых данных относительно другого

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list, сортировка

Есть списки строковых данных (`to_sort_a, to_sort_b`), которые нужно отсортировать относительно `origin_list`, с оглядкой на этот список, так чтобы элементы имеющиеся в `origin_list` имели тот же самый порядок.

```
origin_list = ['АС7-АС9', 'АС9', 'АС10_0-2', 'АС11_0', 'АС12_0']
to_sort_a = ['АС', 'АС9', 'АС8', 'АС7-АС9']
to_sort_b = ['АС10_0-2', 'АС10_1-3', 'АС11_00', 'АС12_0', 'АС11_01', 'АС11_02', 'АС11_1', 'АС11_0']
```

По итогу должны получаться следующие списки:

```
sorted_a = ['АС', 'АС8', 'АС7', 'АС7-АС9', 'АС9']
sorted_b = ['АС10_0-2', 'АС11_0', 'АС12_0', 'АС10_1-3', 'АС11_00', 'АС11_01', 'АС11_02', 'АС11_1']
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Как это — относительно другого?

Comment: @Глеб, имеется ввиду сортировка с оглядкой на первоначальный список, с сохранением такого же порядка имеющихся элементов

Comment: Как можно сохранять тот же порядок и при этом сортировать? Что-то о-о-очень мутное. Приведите пример, а то понять трудно что-то.

Comment: @Глеб, сейчас поправлю формировку

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Напишите в вопросе не только что у вас на входе, но и что на выходе должно получиться примером. И какой принцип всё-таки, почему такие-то элементы там-то получились.

Comment: @CrazyElf Как я понимаю при сортировке второго массива должен изменятся порядок первого массива так же, как мы изменяем элементы.

Comment: Почему после сортировки в списке появляется новый элемент?

Comment: Судя по результату, получается, что в первом списке сначала должны быть элементы, которых нет в `origin_list`, а потом те, которые есть в `origin_list` с той же сортировкой. А во втором списке наоборот - сначала те, которые есть в `origin_list` и в той же сортировке, а потом те, которых нет в `origin_list`. Так? Странный принцип, но первый шаг - это понять что вы вообще хотите. В итоге возможно сортировка вся сведётся к использованию `sort` с подходящим ключом сортировки.

Comment: До сих пор не ответили?) Я занят был... Ладно щас отвечу

Answer (score 1):

Ну если я правильно понял...

```py
list1 = ["b", "c", "a"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
zipList = list(zip(list1, list2)) # [("b", 1), ("c", 2), ("a", 3)]
zipList.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) # Сортируем по первому значению
list1, list2 = list(zip(*zipList)) # распаковываем
# list1 = ("a", "b", "c")
# list2 = (3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: к сожалению не то

Comment: @qwert Ладно, сегодня попробую перечитать комментарии и вглядеться в пример...